# Is it possbile to put image logo in Template Strings (React js)

Tags: react-native

for printing receipts I am using `Template strings` so it looks like this

```
 <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => {
         var textToPrint =  
        
        `
        --------------------------------
        how to put image logo here
        --------------------------------
        ${GLOBAL.USERNAME} 
        ${new Date().getDate()}
        Bestell ID: ${props.currentorder.order.OrderID}
        --------------------------------
        Kunde:
        ${props.currentorder.order.firstname} ${props.currentorder.order.lastname}
        ${props.currentorder.order.phone}
        
        Adresse:
        ${props.currentorder.order.address} 
        ${props.currentorder.order.zip} ${props.currentorder.order.city}
        
        ********************************
        ${(props.currentorder.order.payment==='cash'?"BARGELD":'Online – Bestellung schon bezahlt')}
        ******************************** 
    --------------------------------`
 BtPrint(textToPrint)
                }}
              >
                <Text>Print</Text>
              </TouchableHighlight>
```

Is there any way that on the begining of the recipe in this text I can put image logo?

Thank you so much

Comment: how do you render this var?
You can use data URLs to place images along with markup
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs
But in case of JSX the only out of the box way to render HTML from variable is
https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: if `BtPrint` encapsulates window.print you can use regular HTML and data URLs to draw images.

Comment: Could you please post it as answer and show me how....thank you

Comment: any way what library stands behind BtPrint? Ive found the following with support of images
https://github.com/januslo/react-native-bluetooth-escpos-printer

Comment: This is btPrint function `async function BtPrint(prn){
    var S = "#Intent;scheme=rawbt;";
    var P =  "package=ru.a402d.rawbtprinter;end;";
    var textEncoded = encodeURI(prn);
    console.log(prn)

    // global.window.location.href="intent:"+textEncoded+S+P;
    let supported = await Linking.canOpenURL("intent:"+textEncoded+S+P);
    if (supported){
await Linking.openURL("intent:"+textEncoded+S+P);
    }
    else{
      ToastExample.show("Install RawBT driver for thermal ESC/POS printer App",ToastExample.LONG)
    }
   
    
}`